# Cascading dropdown mvc3, razor, entity framework 4.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, razor, drop-down-menu

is there an easy way to create cascading dropdowns in mvc3???

what i have done by now is two dropdown, one for students and the next for exams.

what i want to achieve is that if i select X student in the first dropdown, the other dropdown  must show me only the exams of that particular student.

in the database there is an intermediate table between student (idstudent, name, lastname...) and exams (idexam, name, date, grade), this table is studentexam (id studentexam, id student, id exam, grade)..

for now i just know how to show all the student and all the courses in their respectives dropdowns XD! (well i didn't even know how to do that, mvc3 does it automatically)

when i say and easy way, i mean really easy.. ive searched a lot and there are stuff using jquery or ajax and is just too much for my brain right now XD!! im totally new in visual studio, mvc3, razor, entity framework etc.. so if you add to that ajax and jquery stuff i begin to colapse immediately.

so the kind of answer im looking for, is "add this code (well explained) to the controller, and this one to the view lol)

thanks!

Comment: jaja There's not an "easy way" to do this, and your option it has to be a ajax called from the client to refresh the values when the first dropdown it's selected

Comment: you could check my answer to this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077823/how-to-filter-drop-down-list-based-on-previous-selection/11102704#11102704