# Cascading Dropdown Lists in ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm working on creating two dropdown lists for a form. The first is a list of Areas and the second needs to filter to the Job Types based on the selected Area.

I'm basing the majority of my code on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077823/how-to-filter-drop-down-list-based-on-previous-selection/11102704#11102704), but am having trouble getting the Job Types list to show in the View. I can see the correct options being appended when debugging, but am stuck on why they are not populating the Job Type dropdown list.

The View

```
                <!--Area Dropdown-->
                @Html.DropDownList("areas", null , new { @class = "col s12 m6 l3" })

                <!--Job Type Dropdown-->
                @Html.DropDownList("jobType", Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "Job Type", new { @class = "col s12 m6 l3" })
```

The controller code, which is populating my first dropdown box (Area)

```
var jobArea = (from a in db.tblJobTypes
                           where a.Active == true
                           select a.Department).Distinct().ToList();
ViewData["areas"] = new SelectList(jobArea);
```

The POST action within the controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult JobTypeByArea(string area)
    {

        var test = (from a in db.tblJobTypes
                      where a.Active == true && a.Department == area
                      select new
                      {
                          id = a.JobTypeID,
                          job = a.JobType
                      }).ToList();
        return Json(test, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

And finally, the JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {   

$('#areas').change(function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/JobTypeByArea',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { area: $(this).val() },
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            var options = '';
            var category = $('#jobType');
            $.each(data, function () {
                options += '<option value="' + this.id + '">' + this.job + '</option>';
            });

            $('#jobType').append(options);
        },
    });
});
});
```

Comment: To be clear - when you debug the client side code, you see `success` handler being called, and `each` executed, and then `append` also executed, all without any errors. Yet after all of that drop down is empty. is that the case?

Comment: In your method `JobTypeByArea()`, change the return type to `JsonResult` instead of `ActionResult`.

Comment: @Andrei Correct. I can step through the code and see each option populating. But when I go to the page the dropdown is empty.

Comment: @Eric Unfortunately that didn't solve it. I had tried that before posting, just to make sure I wasn't missing anything, but it still showed blank.

Comment: @0x1F4, great. Can you add to the post the value that `options` holds just before line `$('#jobType').append(options);` is executed?

Comment: @Andrei Absolutely. It lists out the corresponding job types for the selected area.   `<option value=ExampleOne></option><option value=ExampleTwo></option><option value=ExampleThree>`   I think that I just realized that it's not actually putting the job into the option. Instead, it's making those jobs the value, which is why it's not showing.

Comment: @0x1F4, yeah, i've noticed it before as well, but if that was the case you would see a list of empty-texted items, so to say. And it would appear in markup. I was assuming this is not what is happening though

Comment: @Andrei I altered it a bit to where the id would show as the value and the job would be option. I can look at the markup in the inspector in Chrome and see the correct options, but not when I click the dropdown. I've never seen that happen before.

Comment: @0x1F4, yeah, that is very weird. Not sure if SO even the right place to ask this question, sounds more like a browser problem. Is [this thread](http://askubuntu.com/q/641098/226974) of any help? Does it happen in other browsers as well? If it does (which i doubt), then very stupid question really, but are you sure you are looking at the correct select element?

Comment: @Andrei I followed the guide that the top comment left on that post, but it still didn't fix the issue. I've tested on both Chrome and IE11 (my company uses IE, so that's the main browser) and it doesn't show in either. I decided to make an alert that shows the options based on the area selected so I know that it's working...just not appending to that dropdown. Like you said, it's very weird.